# How To Change Logo Size And Hide Some Div On Scroll Down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want to shrink my logo and hide some div and change menubar position on scroll.I shrink my nav bar on scroll but on shrink menuitem position and logo is not shrinking like,
i want to hide my div class contact_details and change div class nav_bar margin and size of logo on right

```
<header>
    <div class="top_nav">
    <div class="logo">
        <a id="site-logo" href="#"><img src="#" alt="LOGO"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="contact_details">
            <p>Need Help, Call: 062 445676654 |<a href="#"> Mail</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="nav_bar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Solution</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Partners</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<div class="container">
</div>
<div class="site-dt">

</div>

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/* Top Menu Start Here */

.top_nav{
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    position: fixed;
}

.top_nav .logo{
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    height: 75px;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
}

.contact_details{
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 1115px;
    min-height: 25px;
    min-width: 230px;
    float: right;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
}

.contact_details p{
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
}

.contact_details p a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}

.nav_bar{
    margin-left: 700px;
    margin-top: 55px;
    position: absolute;
}

.nav_bar ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}

.nav_bar ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}

.nav_bar ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 12px;
    margin: 8px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
}

.nav_bar ul li a::after{
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    width: 0px;
    height: 5px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    background: #ff6600;
    transition: width .4s;
}

.nav_bar ul li a:hover::after{
    width: 100%;

}

.container{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: url("https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/styles/image_card_4x3_ratio/public/thumbnails/image/leisa_christmas_false_color.png?itok=Jxf0IlS4");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

.site-dt{
    background-color: #00d03e;
    height: 573px;
    width: 100%;
}


    $(function()
{
      var navStatesInPixelHeight = [65,90];

      var changeNavState = function(nav, newStateIndex) {
        nav.data('state', newStateIndex).stop().animate({
          height : navStatesInPixelHeight[newStateIndex] + 'px'
        }, 600);
      };

      var boolToStateIndex = function(bool) {
        return bool * 1;    
      };

      var maybeChangeNavState = function(nav, condState) {
        var navState = nav.data('state');
        if (navState === condState) {
          changeNavState(nav, boolToStateIndex(!navState));
        }
      };

      $('.top_nav').data('state', 1);

      $(window).scroll(function(){
        var $nav = $('.top_nav');

        if ($(document).scrollTop() > 0) {
          maybeChangeNavState($nav, 1);
        } else {
          maybeChangeNavState($nav, 0);
        }
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add class `.fixed-nav` on `.top_nav` class when `scrollTop()` position is greater then 0 and simple remove added class in `else` statement
and write CSS accordingly that class `.fixed-class-name`

**Check jQuery code for Scroll**

```
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var $nav = $('.top_nav');
    var scrolTop = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scrolTop > 0) {
      $nav.addClass("fixed-nav");
    } else {
      $nav.removeClass("fixed-nav");
    }
  });
```

```js
$(function() {
  var navStatesInPixelHeight = [65, 90];

  var changeNavState = function(nav, newStateIndex) {
    nav.data('state', newStateIndex).stop().animate({
      height: navStatesInPixelHeight[newStateIndex] + 'px'
    }, 600);
  };

  var boolToStateIndex = function(bool) {
    return bool * 1;
  };

  var maybeChangeNavState = function(nav, condState) {
    var navState = nav.data('state');
    if (navState === condState) {
      changeNavState(nav, boolToStateIndex(!navState));
    }
  };

  $('.top_nav').data('state', 1);

  //Scroll Script here
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var $nav = $('.top_nav');
    var scrolTop = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scrolTop > 0) {
      $nav.addClass("fixed-nav");
    } else {
      $nav.removeClass("fixed-nav");
    }
  });

});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
/* Top Menu Start Here */

.top_nav {
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  position: relative;
  transition:all 0.7s ease;
  -webkit-transition:all 0.7s ease;
  -moz-transition:all 0.7s ease;
  -o-transition:all 0.7s ease;
  -ms-transition:all 0.7s ease;
}
.top_nav .logo {
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  height: 75px;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  transition:all 0.7s ease;
  -webkit-transition:all 0.7s ease;
  -moz-transition:all 0.7s ease;
  -o-transition:all 0.7s ease;
  -ms-transition:all 0.7s ease;
}
.contact_details {
  background: yellow;
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 230px;
  float: right;
  color: #fff;
  transition:all 0.7s ease;
  -webkit-transition:all 0.7s ease;
  -moz-transition:all 0.7s ease;
  -o-transition:all 0.7s ease;
  -ms-transition:all 0.7s ease;
}
.contact_details p {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
}
.contact_details p a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}
.nav_bar {
  width: 500px;
  float: right;
  background: orange;
}
.nav_bar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.nav_bar ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}
.nav_bar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 12px;
  margin: 8px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}
.nav_bar ul li a::after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0px;
  height: 5px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: #ff6600;
  transition: width .4s;
}
.nav_bar ul li a:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url("https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/styles/image_card_4x3_ratio/public/thumbnails/image/leisa_christmas_false_color.png?itok=Jxf0IlS4");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
.site-dt {
  background-color: #00d03e;
  height: 573px;
  width: 100%;
}
/*Style after scroll*/

.fixed-nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px
}
.fixed-nav .logo {
  height: 45px;
  width: 127px;
}
.fixed-nav .logo img {
  width: 100%
}
.fixed-nav .contact_details {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div class="top_nav">
    <div class="logo">
      <a id="site-logo" href="#">
        <img src="http://www.robinwhale.co.uk/pages/wisdom/sigs_files/google-logo.jpg" alt="LOGO">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="contact_details">
      <p>Need Help, Call: 062 445676654 |<a href="#"> Mail</a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="nav_bar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Solution</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Support</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Partners</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contacts</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="container">
</div>
<div class="site-dt">

</div>
```

Hope it's relevant for you :)

Comment: its hidding div its not looking pretty can u do some animation in it ?

Comment: make look pretty as per your requirement, and let me check for animation

Comment: how to change child div class using jquery ?
like in css we use (.header p a) so to use in jquery ?

Comment: to change child div class, first select the div and use `addClass()`, you can use css selector in jQuery

Answer (score 1):

**css**

```
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    background-color: #0683c9;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: height 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: height 0.3s;
    -o-transition: height 0.3s;
    transition: height 0.3s;
}
header h1#logo {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 150px;
    line-height: 150px;
    float: left;
    font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
    font-size: 60px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 400;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
header nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}
header nav a {
    line-height: 150px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    color: #9fdbfc;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 18px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
header nav a:hover {
    color: white;
}
header.smaller {
    height: 75px;
}
header.smaller h1#logo {
    width: 150px;
    height: 75px;
    line-height: 75px;
    font-size: 30px;
}
header.smaller nav a {
    line-height: 75px;
}

@media all and (max-width: 660px) {
    header h1#logo {
        display: block;
        float: none;
        margin: 0 auto;
        height: 100px;
        line-height: 100px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    header nav {
        display: block;
        float: none;
        height: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    header nav a {
        line-height: 50px;
        margin: 0 10px;
    }
    header.smaller {
        height: 75px;
    }
    header.smaller h1#logo {
        height: 40px;
        line-height: 40px;
        font-size: 30px;
    }
    header.smaller nav {
        height: 35px;
    }
    header.smaller nav a {
        line-height: 35px;
    }
}
```

**html**

```
<header>
    <div class="container clearfix">
        <h1 id="logo">
            LOGO
        </h1>
        <nav>
            <a href="">Lorem</a>
            <a href="">Ipsum</a>
            <a href="">Dolor</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header><!-- /header -->
```

**js**

```
function init() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
        var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
            shrinkOn = 300,
            header = document.querySelector("header");
        if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
            classie.add(header,"smaller");
        } else {
            if (classie.has(header,"smaller")) {
                classie.remove(header,"smaller");
            }
        }
    });
}
window.onload = init();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is full code , I hope that will help you

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="menu" class="default">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Design</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Development</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Freebies</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Inspiration</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Tutorials</a></li>
<li><a href="#">WordPress</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<!-- close menu --> 
<!-- close navi -->

<div id="content">
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
</div>
<!-- content --> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="nagging-menu.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<div style="text-align:center;clear:both">
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-36251023-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```
body {
background: #efefef;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: none;
text-align: center;
font: normal 13px Verdana, sans-serif;
color: #222;
}
#navi {
height: 50px;
margin-top: 50px;
}
#menu {
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #426d9c), color-stop(40%, #0f67a1), color-stop(100%, #1384d1));
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #426d9c, #0f67a1, #1384d1);
border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
line-height: 50px;
text-align: center;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
}
#content {
width: 750px;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-bottom: 25px;
padding: 30px 0;
text-align: left;
}
ul {
padding: 0;
}
ul li {
list-style-type: none;
display: inline;
margin-right: 15px;
}
ul li a {
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
padding: 3px 7px;
border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-transition-property: color, background;
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s, 0.5s;
}
ul li a:hover {
background: #01458e;
color: #ff0;
-webkit-transition-property: color, background;
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s, 0.5s;
}
.default {
width: 850px;
height: 50px;
box-shadow: 0 5px 20px #888;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 20px #888;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 20px #888;
}
.fixed {
position: fixed;
top: -5px;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
box-shadow: 0 0 40px #222;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 40px #222;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 40px #222;
}
```

**nagging-menu.js**

```
$(function(){

    var menu = $('#menu'),
        pos = menu.offset();

        $(window).scroll(function(){
            if($(this).scrollTop() > pos.top+menu.height() && menu.hasClass('default')){
                menu.fadeOut('fast', function(){
                    $(this).removeClass('default').addClass('fixed').fadeIn('fast');
                });
            } else if($(this).scrollTop() <= pos.top && menu.hasClass('fixed')){
                menu.fadeOut('fast', function(){
                    $(this).removeClass('fixed').addClass('default').fadeIn('fast');
                });
            }
        });

});
```

Please let me know in case of any issue

Comment: You can add some fiddler.

Answer (score -1):

if you use jquery see this jquery plugin [ScrollMagic](http://scrollmagic.io/)
some  [Example](http://scrollmagic.io/examples/index.html)

> if you want to create it yourself watch this

```js
$(function(){
 var shrinkHeader = 300;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = getCurrentScroll();
      if ( scroll >= shrinkHeader ) {
           $('.header').addClass('shrink');
        }
        else {
            $('.header').removeClass('shrink');
        }
  });
function getCurrentScroll() {
    return window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }
});
```

```css
.header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: gray;
    color:#fff;
    z-index: 1000;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: height 0.3s;
    transition: height 0.3s;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:160px;

}
.header.shrink {
    height: 100px;
    line-height:80px;
}
.header h1
{
    font-size:30px;
    font-weight:normal;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.header.shrink h1
{
    font-size:24px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
.content
{
height:2000px;
 /*just to get the page to scroll*/
}
```

```html
   
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <h1>Animated Fixed Header (Scroll Down)</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: how to change child elements class using jquery ?